# HTTPS Sites are not working when i am using Titanium web Proxy

Tags: c#, .net, firefox, x509certificate, titanium-web-proxy

Iam using Titanium web proxy to track all HTTP/HTTPS Request and Response.Here is the link to download the Titanium web Proxy https://github.com/justcoding121/Titanium-Web-Proxy

Now iam facing issue in Firefox that its not allowing me to browse through HTTPS sites as its saying

[image]

i had gone through many site but i haven't found a solution. how can i make my certificate trust root for firefox using c#. i want to do it programatically.i want to make it like fiddlercore its install certificate for all type of browser's

Comment: before down vote please mention the reason so that i could know whats wrong in that question.

Comment: Maybe user's are downvoting, because there is no real question in your posting here?

Answer (score 0):

It seems like it is currently broken.

Other users reports same problem.

Some issues have been opened [here](https://github.com/justcoding121/Titanium-Web-Proxy/issues/180) and [here](https://github.com/justcoding121/Titanium-Web-Proxy/issues/24)